# JavaScript in Select Option classes

Tags: javascript, html

i came here because i don't know how to solve this problem and i'm running out of time, so i have knowledge in html, css, php and other languajes but i am new in javascript. I would like to know how to make a combobox made with select and option tags to work. The problem is that i want to hide and show a number of "tr" items and to fullfill that i need to use class or tags functions not id. For example the code is:

```
    <script>

function toggleOption(thisselect) {
var selected = thisselect.options[thisselect.selectedIndex].value;
toggleRow(selected);
}

function toggleRow(id) {
var row = document.getElementById(id);
if (row.style.display == '') {
row.style.display = 'none';
}
else {
row.style.display = '';
}
}

function showRow(id) {
var row = document.getElementById(id);
row.style.display = '';
}

function hideRow(id) {
var row = document.getElementById(id);
row.style.display = 'none';
}

function hideAll() {
hideRow('2014');
hideRow('2013');
hideRow('2012');
hideRow('2011');
}

</script>
```

My HTML is something like this.

```
<tr class="2014">texto1</tr>
<tr class="2014">texto2</tr>
<tr class="2014">texto3</tr>
<tr class="2013">texto1</tr>
<tr class="2013">texto2</tr>
<tr class="2013">texto3</tr>
<tr class="2012">texto1</tr>
<tr class="2012">texto2</tr>
<tr class="2012">texto3</tr>

<select id="options">
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
</select>
```

It works with the above code but it only hides and id i mean one tr i need to hide all "2014 tr's":

I hope you can understand what i mean. I will be gratefull for any suggest.

I use multiple classes inside the tr's so i need to show only the years.

Comment: You're missing `<td>` inside `<tr>` :)

Comment: can you provide me code fiddle

Comment: yea i put an example with only two trs but i have to use more trs and tds so i have to use classes to hide two, three or more tables at the same time. http://jsfiddle.net/mCeF5/

Comment: Hi @HomerO your fiddle has so many errors. reduce the content in table and make it as error free

Comment: Ready i reduced the code so it will be easy to understand. This table has more years than me lol!!!

Comment: forgot the link http://jsfiddle.net/mCeF5/7/

Answer (score 2):

In your html you used `class`

`<tr class="2014">texto1</tr>` like so. In this case change your script

`document.getElementById();` to `document.getElementsByClassName();`

So as per your code I think you want to `hide` the `tr's`, so `document.getElementsByClassName();` gives `out put` as `array`. so `loop the elements` and make the `css class what you want`.

Comment: I tried this but it's not working with classes. I want to use classes not id the example is because i need an script that works with classes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an ID in order to getElementById

```
<tr id="2012"><td>2012</td></tr>
```

Comment: I know but it's not what i want, i need to use classes not ids.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: document.querySelector()
for hide all:
`document.querySelector('tr');`

for hide by class name:
`document.querySelector('.className');`